# Legacy Webforms User Login/Session not persisted after redirect from iframe in Safari

Tags: asp.net, cookies, safari, opayo

I have a site which uses are a payment service that exists inside an iframe to take the customers credit card information.

In Chrome/Edge everything is working as expected, but in Safari, when the user is redirected back to the site via the iframe (the user is broken out of the iframe when returned to the site) the user is logged out and returned to the login screen.

This is seems to be something that has happened in the last few months but this may have just not be noticed.  I am trying to wrap my head around the SameSite cookie information out there as this may be related.

Has anyone experienced anything like this and have any clue as to how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds very much like a SameSite problem.

A quick way to test that theory would be to set SameSite=None and test if it now works, then work back from there.

The fact that it works on Chrome but not Safari could suggest some quirk of Safari's implementation of SameSite.

I've found the following useful in learning about this:

https://web.dev/samesite-cookie-recipes/
https://www.netsparker.com/blog/web-security/same-site-cookie-attribute-prevent-cross-site-request-forgery/
https://andrewwburns.com/2020/08/05/dont-be-lax-about-your-samesite-cookies/